# Weird Heroku issue rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, localhost

So I have rails app hosted on Heroku. For some reason the admin panel of my app on localhost and on the heroku site are looking different.

And the issue is causing it, the app is behaving differently too, plus the css is not loading properly as well. Since the app works well on localhost, I am assuming above scenario.

I am adding screenshot of both cases below. First is on herolu app and second one is on localhost [image: this is on the heroku url]

[image: this is on localhost]

If you see the icons on the right side they are different plus the refresh button's icons are looking different too.

So my point is, Is something wrong with Heroku?

Comment: That could be because of the way your app is loading this icons. Are you using FontAwesome or something? Check the paths may solve your problems

Comment: I am using font awesome, but how can that affect the icons? And If it is doing so it should look same on localhost as well right

Comment: Can you give us a bigger screenshot of Heroku situation? Are you loading FontAwesome locally on your host or loading it from any CDN?

Comment: Ok, my bad, not using font awesome. the code was commented

Comment: Have you done an asset precompile before your last push to heroku?  If not it won't have your latest css/icon changes.

Comment: I have done asset precompile @MaxWilliams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer as such but a debugging strategy.

On the live site:

- right click on an icon
- inspect it using chrome inspector or similar dev tool
- look at where the image is coming from - there will be a url in the style rule, presumably
- load this url in a new tab and look at the image
- work out whether it's getting it from your filesystem or an external site

Now do the same on your local version.  At one of the above steps you should see where the difference occurs.  This will tell you what's the *actual* cause of your problem (as opposed to describing the symptoms, which is what your question does), and then you can try to work out WHY that problem is occuring.